# How to enforce the default execution order of the nx affected target tasks as specified

Tags: nrwl-nx, nx-affected

When I use the affected command of Nx with for example these targets

```
nx affected --targets=lint,test,e2e,build,deploy
```

and I do not use `dependsOn` in my `project.json` to explicitly tell Nx the order, the execution of the targets is quite random and everything fails because for example deploy will be executed *before* build and test.

What is the default order of execution of the targets specified in the `nx affected` command and how can you enforce the order of being kept on a global level, without having to specify it via `dependsOn` in every `project.json`?